# ansible/jinja2 get unique subelements

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

I got a list like this:

```
host_depends:
  - host: abc
    depends:
      - name: item1
      - name: item4
        type: asdf
      - name: item6
  - host: def
    depends:
      - name: item2
      - name: item4
      - name: item6
```

I need to loop over the unique name of the `depends` elemnents, so in this example I want to loop over

```
- item1 
- item2
- item4
- item6
```

Basically what

```
debug: var=item.1.name
with_subelements:
  - "{{ host_depends }}"
  - depends
```

does, but with unique elements only.

How can I get the `depends` of all `host_depends` items so I can run a `unique` filter over them and use them with `with_items`?

Edit:

I manage to get a list of all `depends` items like this:

```
host_depends|map(attribute='depends')|list
```

But from there, I fail to reduce this list to the `name` items.

Answer (score 2):

If things get too complicated with Ansible and you can't map you mind around it, it's an indicator that it shouldn't be done. Maybe it's possible with some Jinja filters and some `set_fact` tasks in a loop. But don't, Ansible is not a programming language and should not be used as such. Ansible has two main strengths: readability and extensibility. Don't break the first by ignoring the latter.

`with_subelements` is in fact a plugin itself, just that it is a core plugin. Just copy it and create your own `with_unique_subelements` plugin. Here is the [code of with_subelements](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/lookup/subelements.py). Line 100 is where the elements are added to the return list. That's where you can hook in and implement a check if that item already was added.

Save your modified version relative to your playbook as `lookup_plugins/unique_subelements.py` or if you use Ansible 2 you can also store it with the same path inside any role.

Answer (score 2):

```
host_depends|map(attribute='depends')|list
```

returns a list of lists, as depends is a list. To flatten/combine this list of lists into one list, use the builtin flatten lookup:

```
lookup('flattened', host_depends|map(attribute='depends')) |map(attribute='name')|unique|list
```

Comment: Interesting! I can't find this lookup documented anywhere.

Answer (score 1):

`host_depends|map(attribute='depends')|list` returns a list of lists, as `depends` is a list.
To flatten/combine this list of lists into one list:

Add this as `roles/<rolename>/filter_plugins/filter.py`:

```
from ansible import errors

# This converts a list of lists into a single list
def flattenlist(l):
    try:
        return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
    except Exception, e:
        raise errors.AnsibleFilterError('split plugin error: %s' % str(e) )

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' A filter to split a string into a list. '''
    def filters(self):
        return {
            'flattenlist' : flattenlist
        }
```

And use

```
host_depends|map(attribute='depends')|flattenlist|map(attribute='name')|unique|list
```

Comment: How do you use it? Do you still use it together with `with_subelements:`?

Comment: @MaxU No, this is a flat list, so use `with_items` to iterate over its items.