# Unique Filter of List in Jinja2

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2

I have the following YAML structure:

```
bri:
  cards:
    - slot: "1"
      subslot: "0"
      ports: 2
    - slot: "1"
      subslot: "1"
      ports: 2
    - slot: "1"
      subslot: "2"
      ports: 2
    - slot: "2"
      subslot: "0"
      ports: 2
    - slot: "2"
      subslot: "1"
      ports: 2
```

I am attempting to use Jinja2 to get a unique list of **slots**, i.e.:

```
['1', '2']
```

So far, I've managed to apply the following:

```
{{ bri.cards|map(attribute='slot')|list }}
```

Which gives me:

```
['1', '1', '1', '2', '2']
```

However, I don't seem to be able to find a way to get a unique list.

#### Ansible

Ansible appears to have a "unique" filter that can do this.  But I'm not using Ansible in this case.

- http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_filters.html#set-theory-filters
- [ansible/jinja2 get unique subelements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36228816/ansible-jinja2-get-unique-subelements)

#### My question

Can anyone suggest the best way to achieve this?  Should (or can) this be done natively with Jinja2, or should I adopt an alternative approach?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Since jinja2 `2.10`

A `unique` filter was added in version `2.10` (released 2017-11-08). You can check the [change log](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/changelog/) and the [PR](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/pull/469).

### Usage example

```
from jinja2 import Template


template = Template("""
  {% for x in a|unique %}
    <li>{{ x }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
""")

r = template.render(a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 5, 4])

print(r)
```

Output:

```
<li>1</li>

<li>2</li>

<li>3</li>

<li>4</li>

<li>5</li>
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do something like this (depends on how you parse the `.yaml` file - is it a list of dicts of dicts?):

```
{% set slots = [] %}
{% for slot in bri.cards if slot not in slots %}
    {% do slots.append(slot) %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the best I can find.

Beyond this point, I think I should leverage Ansible or move some of the heavy lifting out of the templating engine.  It's a pity that there isn't a filter for this natively.  I may put in a feature request, for what it's worth.

Comment: Good solution when dealing with complex elements the list (i.e. dict) rather than simple types

Answer (score 6):

**Edited** - I did not see the bit about not being able to use the unique filter.
For those that can use the **unique filter** you can do it this way

```
{{ bri.cards|map(attribute='slot')|unique|list }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to above by [doru](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44330192/4718055) with the append functions, but I noticed Ansible doesn't load the 'do' module for Jinja2, working around that is possible as such:
{{ bucket.append(client.client_id) }}

```
{% set slots = [] %}
{% for slot in bri.cards if slot not in slots %}
    {{ slots.append(slot) }}
{% endfor %}
```

So using {{}} syntax, you can still issue the append function call, and not have Ansible throw Jinja syntax errors.