# How do I get jinja2 unique filter to work. (Not working as described in doc)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jinja2

Instead of getting a unique list as this example describes: http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#unique

I get `<generator object do_unique at 0x7f64de96a780>`

I found this question: [Unique Filter of List in Jinja2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44329598/unique-filter-of-list-in-jinja2)

And am able to get that code to work but given I have a simple list, this isn't directly useful.

My Code:

```py
from jinja2 import Template
template = Template("{{ ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'FooBar']|unique }}")
r = template.render()
print(r)
```

- Expected: `['foo', 'bar', 'foobar']`
- Actual: `<generator object do_unique at 0x7f64de96a780>`

Comment: Add `|list` to turn a generator into a list. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try looping over that, rather than just printing it:

```
{% for i in ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'FooBar'] | unique %}
    {{ i }}
(% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add `|list` to get all values from generator as list

```
from jinja2 import Template

template = Template("{{ ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'FooBar']|unique|list }}")
r = template.render()
print(r)
```

But mostly generator is used in `for` loop and then you don't need `|list`

```
template = Template("{% for x in ['foo', 'bar', 'foobar', 'FooBar']|unique %}{{ x }}\n{% endfor %}")
r = template.render()
print(r)
```